# Simple plussing using JS

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I have this piece of code:

```
<head>
<script>
    function myFunction()
    {
        var counter = 1;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=counter;
    }
</script>
</head>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Count</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
```

I want the "counter" variable to plus by 1 everytime the button with the onlick "myFunction" is pressed.

I have tried several useless things with no luck and right now the code prints out "1", no matter how many times the button is pressed obviously. How can I make it plus by 1 if the button is pressed?

Comment: Well the first step is putting a `+` in your code somewhere...

Comment: have the variable outside the `myFunction()` and then increment it inside the function and update the innerHTML

Comment: Thanks Javapirate, and are you sure Waleed...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `var counter` outside of the function:

```
var counter = 0;
function myFunction() {
    counter++;
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = counter;
}
```

Basically, what your function is doing is setting the value of counter to 1 everytime, not incrementing it like you want it to.

Comment: Thx, I tried putting the var counter outside of the function and the write:
counter + 1;
but I see writing counter++; works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If this solved the issue, then you should mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you keep redefining counter each time the function is called. Try 

var counter = 1;
    function myFunction()
    {
        counter=counter+1;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=counter;
     }


Instead of your current javascript code

Comment: I got it right now, thanks, I was close to the right place from the beginning the syntax is just another than what i'm used to :-)